# Can a Discord bot copy a message from one channel to another?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot using discord.ext and was wondering if it is possible to have a message in a channel then after a command have the message get copied and pasted in another channel without having the original message delete. The bot has python and runs discord.ext.

Comment: So the tag should be [discord.py]. Then, what you asked is obviously possible, but you need to have the ID of the channel where you want to paste the message.

Answer (score 0):

You can try smth like this:

```
@Bot.command()
async def paste(ctx, ID: int, channel: discord.Channel):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    message = await Bot.fetch_message(ID)
    await channel.send(message.content)
```

Comment: Cool, I will try that out tonight. Thanks

Comment: @SPCcleveland9035, remember that when you write like `x: type` in discord.py you have to mention it like an object when using the command. For example a discord.Channel object must be written in discord like `#channel-name`.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO That is not entirely true. You can use channel ids or even just channel names.

Comment: @NpGamingBoy, right, but when you mention a channel you use the mention and you don't want to go to copy the ID from the channel...